# Only show the first letter of the Month as label of a matplotlib datetime axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, strftime

I know one can change the location and format of datetime axes in matplotlib with `matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()` and `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`.

Now I only want the ticklabels to contain the first letter of the month (e.g. 'J' for 'January'), and there is no such format available in python `strftime`. How would I go about achieving such a thing? Do I manually edit the ticklabels, or can I somehow get the DateFormatter to do what I want?

Minimal Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md

x = pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01', end='2014-12-31', freq='1M')
y = np.random.randn(12)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%b'))  # Only three-letter month format available
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581837/setting-dates-as-first-letter-on-x-axis-using-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks! That question briefly popped up when searching but then vanished. Couldn’t find it again. I’ll remove the question later